# One row only in dynamic alv in a transactional internal table

Tags: abap, alv

How to make a transaction as one row only per customer? For example I have my internal table that needs to show the first order and the second order date of the customer. So my internal table details is like this: [image]

But the outcome of my dynamic alv is like this:

[image]

> For example in the customer no. "0001011111" row. Is it possible to just
>   make it one row like:

```
KUNNR         1stOrder     LITERS1     2ndOrder     LITERS2 
0001011111    20180811       11        20180814       6
```

MY code is like this:

```
DATA: new_table  TYPE REF TO data,
          new_line   TYPE REF TO data,
          alv_layout TYPE lvc_s_layo,
          alv        TYPE REF TO cl_gui_alv_grid.
    FIELD-SYMBOLS: <l_table> TYPE table,
                   <l_line>  TYPE any,
                   <l_field> TYPE any.


    CALL METHOD cl_alv_table_create=>create_dynamic_table
      EXPORTING
        it_fieldcatalog = it_fieldcat
      IMPORTING
        ep_table        = new_table.
    ASSIGN new_table->* TO <l_table>.
    CREATE DATA new_line LIKE LINE OF <l_table>.
    ASSIGN new_line->* TO <l_line>.
    SORT it_main2 BY kunnr.
    DATA(cpy_it_main) = it_main2.
    DATA(replicate_it_main) = it_main2.
    SORT replicate_it_main BY kunnr erdat1 vbeln.
    DELETE ADJACENT DUPLICATES FROM replicate_it_main COMPARING kunnr.
    SORT cpy_it_main BY kunnr vbeln.
    DELETE ADJACENT DUPLICATES FROM cpy_it_main COMPARING vbeln.
    LOOP AT replicate_it_main INTO DATA(wa_replicate).
      dateflag = wa_replicate-erdat1.
      DATA(cust) = wa_replicate-kunnr.
      DATA(x) = 0.
      DATA(y) = 0.
      LOOP AT it_main2 INTO wa_main2 WHERE kunnr = cust.
        DO 2 TIMES.
          dateflag2 = wa_main2-erdat1.
        ENDDO.
        ASSIGN COMPONENT 'KUNNR' OF STRUCTURE <l_line> TO <l_field>.
        <l_field> = wa_main2-kunnr.
        ASSIGN COMPONENT 'NAME1' OF STRUCTURE <l_line> TO <l_field>.
        <l_field> = wa_main2-name1.
        ASSIGN COMPONENT 'KTEXT' OF STRUCTURE <l_line> TO <l_field>.
        <l_field> = wa_main2-ktext.
        ASSIGN COMPONENT 'MONTH' OF STRUCTURE <l_line> TO <l_field>.
        <l_field> = wa_main2-month.
        ASSIGN COMPONENT 'CGRP2' OF STRUCTURE <l_line> TO <l_field>.
        <l_field> = wa_main2-cgrp2.
        IF dateflag = dateflag2.
          ASSIGN COMPONENT 'ERDAT1' OF STRUCTURE <l_line> TO <l_field>.
          <l_field> = wa_main2-erdat1.
          ASSIGN COMPONENT 'BRAND1' OF STRUCTURE <l_line> TO <l_field>.
          <l_field> = wa_main2-brand1.
          ASSIGN COMPONENT 'LITER1' OF STRUCTURE <l_line> TO <l_field>.
          <l_field> = wa_main2-liter1.
          ASSIGN COMPONENT 'VOLUM1A' OF STRUCTURE <l_line> TO <l_field>.
          <l_field> = wa_main2-volum1a.
          ASSIGN COMPONENT 'VOLUM2A' OF STRUCTURE <l_line> TO <l_field>.
          <l_field> = wa_main2-volum2a.
          ASSIGN COMPONENT 'VOLUM3A' OF STRUCTURE <l_line> TO <l_field>.
          <l_field> = wa_main2-volum3a.
          x = 1.
        ELSE.
          ASSIGN COMPONENT 'ERDAT2' OF STRUCTURE <l_line> TO <l_field>.
          <l_field> = wa_main2-erdat1.
          ASSIGN COMPONENT 'BRAND2' OF STRUCTURE <l_line> TO <l_field>.
          <l_field> = wa_main2-brand1.
          ASSIGN COMPONENT 'LITER2' OF STRUCTURE <l_line> TO <l_field>.
          <l_field> = wa_main2-liter1.
          ASSIGN COMPONENT 'VOLUM1B' OF STRUCTURE <l_line> TO <l_field>.
          <l_field> = wa_main2-volum1a.
          ASSIGN COMPONENT 'VOLUM2B' OF STRUCTURE <l_line> TO <l_field>.
          <l_field> = wa_main2-volum2a.
          ASSIGN COMPONENT 'VOLUM3B' OF STRUCTURE <l_line> TO <l_field>.
          <l_field> = wa_main2-volum3a.
          y = 1.
        ENDIF.
        dateflag3 = wa_main2-erdat.
          INSERT <l_line> INTO TABLE <l_table>.
          CLEAR: <l_line>, wa_main2.
      ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: It seems that is because you group by BRAND field which is empty for 0001011111 customer, which means undefined for ALV. Try to populate it to make it group.

Answer (score 0):

to be frank, your code seems a bit confusing. However I think you get multiple rows because you

`INSERT <l_line> INTO TABLE <l_table>`.

This is unnessessary when working with field symbols because they already point to the table entry, hence you're already modifying it. Inserting in the end adds another row in the table and therefore you get two.

I'd advise you to read up on field symbol usage, for example [this tutorial](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/09/05/dynamic-programming-in-abap-part-1-introduction-to-field-symbols/)